# QT - Postgresql - Wait for insert to finish before starting another insert

Tags: sql, qt, postgresql, insert, transactions

I have a program on QT which first inserts values to table with an auto increase column "Table A". Then it joins the values of Table A with Table B to insert into Table C (I need to use the recently created id's on Table C).

My issue is that the program starts inserting to Table C before the inserts on table A are finalized hence the number of records on Table C are incomplete.

If I run the insert on table A manually, then wait and insert on table C all the records are displayed, so the queries are correct.

CODE

```
_query.exec("Insert into tableA values(...........)"); --This inserts 3000 records
_query.exec("Insert into tableC (select * from tableA)"); --This inserts 2500 values
```

If I comment the second query on the code and execute it

```
_query.exec("Insert into tableA values(...........)"); --This inserts 3000 records

//_query.exec("Insert into tableC (select * from tableA)");
```

Then run the query on pgphpadmin

```
Insert into tableC (select * from tableA) --This inserts 3000 records
```

It does insert the 3000 records

My  guess is that the program doesn't wait for the first insert to finish before continuing to the next query.

Comment: You can request a lock on table A. This way the secong process will be blocked till the lock is released.

Comment: Please see the code on the updated question

Comment: I tried to lock the table but it doesn't work, I believe because it sends the commit right after the lock it gets released before the insert transaction is finalized.

Comment: Is there a `commit` method in the `connection` or `cursor`?

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that the program doesn't wait for the first insert to
>   finish before continuing to the next query.

As of Qt-5.3, the QPSQL postgres driver uses the synchronous `PQexec()` call to implement `QSqlQuery::exec()`, so it's impossible that it returns before a query is entirely finished.

Besides, even if it used an asynchronous call like `PQsendQuery()`, this situation would still be not possible, because the same connection cannot start a new SQL statement until it's done with the previous one.

Your program would need to have multiple open connections in multiple threads to submit parallel queries. That's not the kind of thing that happens inadvertently.

And even if it had these, the effect of a half-finished INSERT cannot be seen from any other connection because of the [isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) properties of transactions. The second INSERT would either see no row at all from the first INSERT if it's not finished/committed yet, or all the rows if it's finished/committed.

The rare situation when half-loaded data may be seen from outside the server is with [`COPY FREEZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), but that's not INSERT.

Comment: so what you are saying is that ::exec() doesn't return true until the insert is totally finished?

Answer (score 0):

I kept investigating and a piece of my code did multi threads.  There was an issue with the threads and the program wasn't waiting for all the threads to complete. That is why it seemed that the program was not waiting enough.

Thanks for your help